# How do I give a custom sorting option in python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Normally it sorts alphabetically. For example I have some variable that are sorted as `'A' > 'B' > 'C' > 'D' > 'E' > 'I'`. But I want to sort these values as `'A' > 'B' > 'C' > 'D' > 'I' > 'E'` but it difficult since `E` goes before I in the alphabet. So, how do I make a custom order to make sure that I goes before `E` in this case scenario using python?

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include your attempt, users are more likely to answer your question that way.

Comment: Look creating pd.Categorical dtypes with order.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to convert your column as an ordered categorical dtype:

```
# Create a new dtype
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'I', 'E'], ordered=True)

# Apply it
df['var'] = df['var'].astype(cat)

# Sort by 'var'
df = df.sort_values('var', ignore_index=True)
```

Before sorting:

```
>>> df
  var  val
0   E    5
1   C    1
2   A    7
3   I    9
4   B    8
5   A    4
6   D    5
7   A    6
8   E    8
9   E    7
```

After sorting:

```
>>> df
  var  val
0   A    7
1   A    4
2   A    6
3   B    8
4   C    1
5   D    5
6   I    9  # As expected, 'I' is before 'E'
7   E    5
8   E    8
9   E    7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating pd.CategoricalDtype like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([*'ABCDEI'], 50), columns=['Letter'])

catdtype = pd.CategoricalDtype([*'ABCDIE'], ordered=True)

df['Letter'] = df['Letter'].astype(catdtype)

df.sort_values('Letter', ascending=False).head(20)
```

Output:

```
   Letter
0       E
3       E
27      E
43      E
9       E
10      E
45      I
29      I
39      I
19      I
13      I
30      I
11      D
23      D
2       D
46      D
18      D
47      D
8       D
28      C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of your keys and use it as an argument to sort the data frame.
Something like this:

```
custom_key = ...
df.sort_values(by= "target column", key= custom_key)
```

Comment: How does this *answer* the question?  OP cannot use this code to solve their issue; it’s a rough prototype, and therefore not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a dataframe you could sort by pulling out the data you need using .where

```
dfe = df.where(df["letter"] == "E")
dfe = dfe.dropna(subset="letter")
```

then re-inserting it at the end using

```
df = pd.concat([df, dfe])
df.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

If this is not a dataframe please provide more information. Also I am aware this is not the "fastest" way of doing it but it should work.

You could also create a key in the `df.sort_values(key=your_list_here)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `enumerate()`

```
d = {c:n for n,c in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'I', 'E'])}
df.sort_values('Var',key = lambda x: x.map(d))
```